# Property does not exist on type Window & typeof globalThis

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

In a Electron-React-Typescript app I'm getting this error:  `Property 'api' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. window.api.send('open-type-A-window', '');`

But in a file index.d.ts  I declared interface Window in this way:

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    declare interface Window {
      "electron": {
          openNewWindow(): void;
      },
      "api": {
          send: (channel, data) => {
              ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data).catch(e => console.log(e))
          },
          receive: (channel, func) => {
            console.log("preload-receive called. args: ");
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
          },
          electronIpcSendTo: (window_id: string, channel: string, ...arg: any) => {
            ipcRenderer.sendTo(window_id, channel, arg);
          },
          electronIpcSend: (channel: string, ...arg: any) => {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, arg);
          },
          electronIpcSendSync: (channel: string, ...arg: any) => {
            return ipcRenderer.sendSync(channel, arg);
          },
          electronIpcOn: (channel: string, listener: (event: any, ...arg: any) => void) => {
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener);
          },
          electronIpcOnce: (channel: string, listener: (event: any, ...arg: any) => void) =>
 {
            ipcRenderer.once(channel, listener);
          },
          electronIpcRemoveListener:  (channel: string, listener: (event: any, ...arg: any) 
=> void) => {
            ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, listener);
          },
          electronIpcRemoveAllListeners: (channel: string) => {
            ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(channel);
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've read this thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19816 but I didn't get the proper solution.

What should I add / modify in order to avoid this error `Property 'api' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'`  ?

- node: v14.5.0
- electron: v11.2.3
- typescript: v4.1.3
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop

Comment: `"api", {` looks like a typo

Comment: @p4m thank you. Unfortunately even after correcting this typo I get `Property 'api' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm not familiar with React.js but I had the same issue with an Electron-Angular application. By adding the following declaration to my app.module.ts file it allows TypeScript to recognize the `api` object in window.

You should be able to do the same by adding to your main module in your TS project.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    api?: any;
  }
}
```

After you should be able to simple execute your code anywhere in your project.

```
if(window.api) {
  window.api.send('ipcChannel', data);
}
```