# Getting Global variable into a Typescript file

Tags: typescript

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

This is my `index.html`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebGL Demo Project : Group 9</title>


</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100vw;height:90vw;display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
    <div style="width:70vw;height:100vw;display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
        <canvas id="canvas" style="height:100vh;width:100vw;border:1px solid black;"/>
    </div>

    <div style="width:30vw;height:100vw;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
        <div> Camera Position </div>
        <div style = "width: 100vw; display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
            <div>Camera X Position </div>
            <div><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="xPosition"  ></div>
        </div>

        <div style = "width: 100vw; display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
            <div>Camera Y Position </div>
            <div><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="yPosition" ></div>
        </div>

        <div style = "width: 100vw; display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
            <div>Camera Z Position </div>
            <div><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="zPosition" ></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <script type="module" src = "index.js"></script>                                            <!-- This file holds the baseline commands -->
    <script type="module" src = "input_controls.js"></script>                           <!-- This file manages the inputs from sliders, color pickers, etc -->
    <script type="module" src = "dist/debug_controls.js"></script>                              <!-- This file produces debug information to be printed in a div -->
    <script type="module" src = "dist/graphics.js"></script>                                    <!-- This file performs graphical computations -->
                                                                                                <!-- It automatically imports math libraries as needed -->
    <script type="module" src = "dist/render.js"></script>                                      <!-- This is the file that communicates with the webGL layer -->
                                                                                                <!-- It recieves computations (such as vertices, interpolations ..)
                                                                                                     from graphics.js, and then dumps the result in webGL layer-->
    <!--<script type="module" src = "dist/index.js"></script>-->                                        <!-- This file holds the baseline commands -->
</body>
</html>
```

I want the logic to control sliders in `generic/input_controls.ts` .

My `tsconfig.json` (path for this file is `/my/path`) is as follows:

```
{


"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],                               /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    "module": "es2015",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",                                    /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                           /* Enable importing .json files. */
    "allowJs": true,                                     /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    "outDir": "./build",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "strictNullChecks":false,                /* turn off the strict null checks to access html elements */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                               /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    "declaration": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]

}
```

The `src` folder and the rest shown in the figure is inside `/my/path`.

I want to have a few global variables defined in `index.d.ts` like this:

```
declare global {

    // ======== input slider controls ========//

    interface window {


        camera_xPosition_webGL_coords : number;
        camera_yPosition_webGL_coords : number;
        camera_zPosition_webGL_coords : number;

    }



}

export const global;
```

Note, I also tried with another interface, such as interface camera.

Now, in `generic/input_controls`, i have:

```
import {global} from '../index.d';

console.log("input controls on");

const slider = document.getElementById('xPosition') as HTMLInputElement;;

slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
    // Update the global variable camera_xPosition_webGL_coords based on the slider value
    window.camera_xPosition_webGL_coords = parseFloat(slider.value);
    console.log("camera x position is: " + window.camera_xPosition_webGL_coords);
});
```

**Problem**

If i run this with `interface window`, then i get a compiler error:

```
src/generic/input_controls.ts:9:12 - error TS2339: Property 'camera_xPosition_webGL_coords' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.

9     window.camera_xPosition_webGL_coords = parseFloat(slider.value);
```

If I run this with `interface camera`, and correct the `input_controls.ts` file accordingly, then compile succeeds, but the file has no effect. Even `console.log("input controls on");` has no effect.

But if i remove the eventlistener, then i get output to console.

**Attempt to resolve**

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120513/property-does-not-exist-on-type-window-typeof-globalthis) and tried to use the `?:` operator, followed by `number` for each of the variables in index.d.ts

It does not lead to any difference.

The AI powered search of stackoverflow with [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=typescript%20eventlistener%20in%20a%20different%20file%20no%20effect) `typescript eventlistener in a different file no effect` produces zero results.

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit based on comment of kelsny:**

If I write the `index.d.ts` as:

```
// ======== input slider controls ========//

declare let camera_xPosition_webGL_coords : number;
declare let camera_yPosition_webGL_coords : number;
declare let camera_zPosition_webGL_coords : number;
```

and the `input_controls.ts` as:

```
console.log("input controls on");

const slider = document.getElementById('xPosition') as HTMLInputElement;;

slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
    // Update the global variable camera_xPosition_webGL_coords based on the slider value
    camera_xPosition_webGL_coords = parseFloat(slider.value);
    console.log("camera x position is: " + camera_xPosition_webGL_coords);
});
```

to avoid exports and imports, I get:

```
❯ tsc -p tsconfig.json
src/generic/input_controls.ts:8:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'camera_xPosition_webGL_coords'.

8     camera_xPosition_webGL_coords = parseFloat(slider.value);
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/generic/input_controls.ts:9:44 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'camera_xPosition_webGL_coords'.

9     console.log("camera x position is: " + camera_xPosition_webGL_coords);
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: src/generic/input_controls.ts:8
```

Comment: **do not use static imports or exports in ambient dts files** as it will turn the dts files into **modules**, which have their **own separate scope**

Comment: You want to augment the `Window` interface, not `window`

Comment: If i do: 

`declare global {

 // ======== input slider controls ========//

 interface Window {


  camera_xPosition_webGL_coords : number;
  camera_yPosition_webGL_coords : number;
  camera_zPosition_webGL_coords : number;

 }



}

export const global;`

I get: 

`Property 'camera_xPosition_webGL_coords' does not exist on type '{ new (): Window; prototype: Window; }'.

9     Window.camera_xPosition_webGL_coords = parseFloat(slider.value);`